# Using OpenZeppelin's increaseTime.js

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm writing a test for a time-dependent solidity function. I'd like to use the [increaseTime.js](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/test/helpers/increaseTime.js) helper from v1.12.0 of OpenZeppelin's library.

When I try to call this helper inside my test, I get an error. For small durations like 1200 (20 minutes), I get a revert error: "Uncaught Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert." For larger durations like 86400 (1 day), I get "VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode."

```
import { increaseTime } from './../contracts/openzeppelin/test/helpers/increaseTime.js';

contract('Kabocha', function(accounts) {
  describe('Pumpkin', async function() {
    it("should do a time-dependent thing", async function() {
      // setup stuff goes here
      await increaseTime(86000);
    }
  }
}
```

Any tips for working with this helper library? Perhaps one day is too far in the future for evm_increaseTime.

I'm using Ganache CLI v6.1.6 (ganache-core: 2.1.5) as my test chain.

**Update:**

In my setup, there is a step that sets a timestamp and compares against block.timestamp. When I comment out everything in the setup including this line, I can call increaseTime with no limit. However, uncommenting the timestamp setter means I can only call increaseTime with a max value of 249.

**Update #2**

Any step involving block.timestamp followed by increaseTime causes my code to revert. Seems like the two don't mix.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86093/discussion-on-question-by-ann-kilzer-using-openzeppelins-increasetime-js).

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, check my question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114701/unable-to-simulate-openingtime-for-a-timedcrowdsale-while-testing